# How to Nest a TelerikGrid inside TelerikForm with Blazor

Tags: forms, blazor, telerik, telerik-grid

I have a TelerikForm with FormItems --> FormGroup --> FormItem(s)  and I am wanting to have in the middle or bottom of my form to have a Grid in which I can add new items with multiple rows.

I was adding in TelerikGrid with GridColumns and it renders but puts the grid at the top of the page.   It has been a while since I used Telerik, so I'm wondering how I can have the nice form , with the nice looking grid inside of it without too much css manipulation.

There is a blazor repl that I'm using as a playground.
https://blazorrepl.telerik.com/wSkHQXwH29FwQkMD29

```
<TelerikForm Model="@TestUser"
                     Width="700px"
                     Columns="2"
                     ColumnSpacing="20px"
                     OnValidSubmit="@HandleValidSubmit"
                     OnInvalidSubmit="@HandleInvalidSubmit">
            <FormValidation>
                <DataAnnotationsValidator></DataAnnotationsValidator>
            </FormValidation>
            <FormItems>
                <FormGroup LabelText="User Information">
            ...................
             <TelerikGrid Data="@items" TItem=GridItem AutoGenerateColumns="false">
               <GridColumns>
                  <GridColumn Field="@nameof(GridItem.Name)" Title="Name" />
                  <GridColumn Field="@nameof(GridItem.Value)" Title="Value" />
              </GridColumns>
             </TelerikGrid>

            </FormItems>
            
/TelerikForm>
```